# EmberJS routing clarification

Tags: ember.js

I'm still new to Ember.js.  The [Nested Resources](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) example states the following:

```
URL:        /post/:post_id/comments/new
Route Name: comments.new
Controller: App.CommentsNewController
Route:      App.CommentsNewRoute
```

Given this:

1. "post" is in the URL, but why is "post" not in the route name, controller or route?
2. How would one disambiguate between new comments in a "post" and new comments in another area?
3. I don't see a templateName option in the route creation code, so would this be set in the controller?

Thank you!

**Edit:** This question is about Ember Pre4.

Answer (score 6):

1. It's because `post` is a resource, `comments` is a resource, whilst `new` is a route. The path for the route **begins** at the **last** resource name, in this case `comments`. I perceive this as a problem, as you've addressed in the second question, so I expect this to change to be `PostCommentsNewController`.
2. You don't disambiguate between them at the moment, but expect this to be in pre 5.
3. There's no need to specify a `templateName` unless you're inserting views manually. For **/#/pets** Ember will first consult `App.PetsRoute`, locate/instantiate `App.PetsController`, and instantiate `App.PetsView`. `App.PetsView` will be inserted into a template which has a `data-template-name` of "**pets**".

Comment: Wow, awesome answer.  Would it be wrong to want to specify an optional controller name with the route?  I think this would provide maximum flexibility when refactoring.  (For example: changing the route for a given view.)  And regarding #2, has this been presented to the good ember folks?  :-)

Comment: I don't think you can specify a different controller name, but you can definitely supply a different view to render (see http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/), I think the reason for this inability is that at the moment it's immediately obvious which controller and view your `PetsRoute` relates to. For #2, most definitely! :)

Comment: Sorry, you can specify a different controller along with the custom view, in `renderTemplate`: `this.render('someTemplate', { controller: "someController" });`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead you can usually use `{{render "someTemplate"}}` for this, see my explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802223/different-rendering-techniques-in-emberjs-handlebars-template/14802424#14802424

Answer (score 2):

Question 3:  The TemplateName to be rendered for a route can be set by using the `this.render`-method documented here:
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: Oh, nice.  So we can specify templates there.  Missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Names for Controllers and Routes are simply determined by nearest Resource I believe.  In the example cited, post is a resource w/ a route of edit hence PostEditController while Comment is also a resource (despite being nested inside Post) so the resulting Controller is CommentsController or CommentsNewController for its nested route "new".

Comment: Exactly.  So if you have two resources that both have a new comments route, you get stuck.  At least in Pre4.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand better the struture of your map by inspecting in your console the routes names and their respective handlers. Good debugging trick :)

```
APP.Router.router.recognizer.names;
```