# EmberJs: How to render a template using its "data-template-name"

Tags: templates, ember.js, nested

I have a template file which only generates some html (so there's no App.ListView). For example assume I have a "list" defined as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="list"> 
    <div class="list">
    </div>
</script>
```

Now the question is how can I target this template within an other template

```
{{view "list" contextBinding="this"}}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xz6t2/1/)

Any suggestions ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{{template}}`.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xz6t2/2/)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{template list}}
</script>
```

See a related answer for a breakdown of the various helpers: [Different rendering techniques in emberjs handlebars template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802223/different-rendering-techniques-in-emberjs-handlebars-template)

Comment: One other thing. In one situation I have the name of the view stored in a variable, how do you render a view like that ? For example: {{view config.viewName}} where config.viewName = "App.PeopleView"

Comment: I think its best to continue my last question in an new thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828372/emberjs-render-template-inside-handlebars-helper)