# EmberJs: render template inside Handlebars-helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, helper

I have this situation in which I have the template-name stored in a variable. I noticed that if you have for example

```
var config = { view: "PeopleView", .... } ;
```

that you can't do

```
{{view App[config.view]}}
```

If this is possible, I'm still interested in the solution!
Anyway, I decided to fix this with a Handlebars helper:

```
{{setVariableView config}}

...

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('setVariableView', function(value, options) {
    return App[value.view].create(value) ; // <-- this doesn't work :)
}) ;
```

At this point I don't know how to call the compiled PeopleView ? 
Any suggestions ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First you'll want to create your configuration object, as you've done:

```
App.config = Ember.Object.create({ view: 'App.MyView' });
```

And then you want to register your helper, which you've done, but it needs to be modified a little bit, since views need to be manually `append`ed when you take this approach:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('setVariableView', function(value, options) {
    var view = eval(value.view).create();
    view.append();
});
```

And now you can pass in the configuration file to your `setVariableView` helper, and it will render the view that was passed in to your configuration:

```
{{setVariableView App.config}}
```

The only concern is the utilisation of `eval`. Maybe it's the early morning that's not helping, but I can't think of a better alternative at the moment.

Comment: You can define config object as `App.config = Ember.Object.create({ app: App, view: 'MyView' });`, and in helper: `var view = value.app[value.view].create();`. This way you don't need to use `eval`:)

Comment: value.app[value.view].create() creates an Object/Class. How to create a string and pass it a context (like: value) ?