# Ember.js view disappears on transition

Tags: view, ember.js, transition, routes

Somehow even in the most simple example I come up with a view disappears when I try to transition to another state/route.

My index route looks like this:

```
--Application-------------------------------
| --Header-------------------------------- |
| | --ViewA----------------------------- | |
| | | View A!                          | | |
| | |__________________________________| | |
| |                                      | |
| | --ViewB----------------------------- | |
| | | View B!                          | | |
| | |__________________________________| | |
| |______________________________________| |
|                                          |
| --Main---------------------------------- |
| | I stay here, no matter what!         | |
| |______________________________________| |
|__________________________________________|
```

As soon as I go to the 'Next" state, ViewB disappears and it looks like this:

```
--Application-------------------------------
| --Header-------------------------------- |
| | --ViewA----------------------------- | |
| | | View A!                          | | |
| | |__________________________________| | |
| |______________________________________| |
|                                          |
| --Main---------------------------------- |
| | I stay here, no matter what!         | |
| |______________________________________| |
|__________________________________________|
```

The behaviour can be seen in this example application http://jsfiddle.net/SAra5/4/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it gets confused and doesn't render all of the outlets if you don't specify it to do anything on the new route. The way to make things work properly would be to include what you want the route to render again in the `NextRoute`.

```
App.NextRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render('header', {'outlet':'header', 'into':'application'});
        this.render('main', {'outlet':'main', 'into':'application'});

        this.render('viewB', {'outlet':'viewB', 'into':'header'});
        this.render('viewA', {'outlet':'viewA', 'into':'header'});
    }
});
```

If you swap `this.render('viewB', {'outlet':'viewB', 'into':'header'});` with `this.render('viewA', {'outlet':'viewA', 'into':'header'});` in the index route before doing the change to `NextRoute`, you'll see that it now only renders viewB! Weird, huh? I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature though at this current point in time.

Comment: It seems like a bug to me, because here's another weird example by a user on IRC. The Views A&B are now referenced in the template but the 'Main' template disappears now: http://jsfiddle.net/ianpetzer/Xdrje/

p.s.: Oh and btw I was of the impression nothing in the DOM changes until I explicitly tell ember to do so. And I can't see any logical reason behind an update of the current DOM just because you change states.

Comment: Oh. If you don't specify the route it seems that the last line of the Route gets ignored and not re-rendered. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Xdrje/1/) jsfiddle.

Comment: Looks like whatever is rendered last disappears on transition to a new state.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on your intended behaviour, but it's better to abstract out your `IndexRoute` because you need the same in every route, otherwise it will be removed: http://jsfiddle.net/SAra5/5/

However, your example seems convoluted. I think the solution for you lies in `{{render}}`. Please see my post here: [Different rendering techniques in emberjs handlebars template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802223/different-rendering-techniques-in-emberjs-handlebars-template/14802424#14802424)

Comment: As you can clearly see in the above comments and answers it only removes the last template you added via this.render(). The reason behind this example is to have an outlet that is kept 'alive' through out the application life time. I need that because I have an embedded flash application which requests permission to the users webcam and camera and which should only be asked for once. as soon as I have to re-add it to the dom it will ask for permission again.

Comment: As an interim solution, you could make the flash application not the last `this.render` in the Route?

Comment: As an actual solution, you can use `{{render}}` to permanently render the Flash application to the screen, no? Outlets are fickle things, and you should be placing persistent views outside of them.