# How do I create a reusable partial for duplicate markup in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, partial-views, reusability

Given this chunk of HTML:

```
<div id="email_field" class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="account.email">Email</label>
  <div id="email_input" class="controls">
    <input id="account.email" name="account.email" type="text" placeholder="jpublic@example.com">
    <span class="help-block">We just need a valid email address.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I turn this into a re-usable partial for whatever attribute I want? IE: email, password, password confirmation, etc.

I would assume some sort of view hierarchy but I'm not quite sure.

**EDIT**: After further exploration I've knocked out `{{view}}` and `{{render}}` and figured out exactly what I need:

I want to:
  1. Use a specific view (InputView)
  2. Use a specific controller (Preferably similarly named: InputController) (`{{view}}` doesn't do this I think)
  3. Be able to use this multiple times (`{{render}}` can't do this)
  4. Be able to pass in values (`{{render}}` can't do this)

Example:

```
<!-- templates/application.hbs -->
{{foo "input" name="Email" id="account.email" placeholder="jpublic@email.com"}}
```

---

```
// controllers/input.js
Application.InputController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  type: "text"
});
```

---

```
// views/input.js
Application.InputView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "form/input"
});
```

---

```
<!-- templates/form/input.hbs -->
<input {{bindAttr id="id" name="name" type="type" placeholder="placeholder"}}>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a view that takes all the parameters that are variable. Such as:

```
{{view App.FormEntity
    name="email"
    placeholder="My placeholder..."
    help="We just need a valid email address."
    valueBinding="value"
}}
```

From there you could extract the label, the various class names, and then use `Ember.TextField` to bind the value to.

Once you have all of those arguments passed into the view, it should be nice and easy to create the markup using a mixture of `bindAttr`s, a couple of computed properties, and Ember helpers (such as the `Ember.TextField`).

Comment: Great response, thanks, but it leaves me wondering what controller does the view look for when using bindAttr? I can't seem to gather that from the docs.

Comment: Well, every view should have access to a controller. By default, if you're in the `IndexRoute` then the index view will have access to `IndexController`, and if you insert a view in that index view, then that view will inherit the `IndexController`. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802223/different-rendering-techniques-in-emberjs-handlebars-template/14802424#14802424

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't help me I guess? I want this helper to have it's own controller. Or more specifically I have computed values that I don't want to attach to IndexController.

Comment: So I've unaccepted the answer because this really only gives one piece to the puzzle, it doesn't actually solve my problem: I want to take this reusable chunk of HTML, make it dynamic, and use it in other templates.

Comment: Then use something like `{{render "input" property="whatever"}}` and it will attach `InputController` to your `InputView`.

Comment: Works for a lot of reasons, but raises an exception when used multiple times :(

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Emberjs and looking for pretty much the same thing, but couldn't you also simply use http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/ for that?
I will try it myself, so can give more updates if that works out.

**Update:**
Ok, I got it to work. I created a new Helpers folder with FormgeneratorHelper.js and the following code:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('control-group', function (options) {
    var name = options.hash.test.capitalize();
    console.log(name);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<div class="control-group"> \
            <label class="control-label" for="input' + name + '">' + name + '</label> \
            <div class="controls"> \
                <input type="text" id="input' + name + '" placeholder="' + name + '" /> \
            </div> \
        </div>');
});
```

An then, no matter in which template you can do:

```
{{control-group test="email"}}
```

I really like the idea of using helpers, but if you are using plain Javascript (as opposed to CoffeScript) and have more than one line of code, then it gets a bit ugly unfortunately. But will probably still use that method.

Comment: While that certainly seems to do what I want, that's definitely not how I want to do it. It becomes unmaintainable that way.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I turn this into a re-usable partial for whatever attribute I want? IE: email, password, password confirmation, etc.

What you want is the experimental `{{control}}` helper. The control helper is currently under development and is considered experimental. To enable it, set `ENV.EXPERIMENTAL_CONTROL_HELPER = true` before requiring Ember.

> I want to:
>   1. Use a specific view (InputView) 
>   2. Use a specific controller (Preferably similarly named: InputController) ({{view}} doesn't do this I think)

Out-of-box the control helper expects to be passed a template name. That template name is used to lookup a matching view and controller. So for example:

```
App.InputView = Ember.View.extend()
App.InputController = Ember.Controller.extend()
{{control input}}
```

See:

- [A control renders a template with a new instance of the named controller and view](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/tests/helpers/control_test.js#L80)
- [A control's controller and view are lookuped up via template name](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/tests/helpers/control_test.js#L91)

> 1. Be able to use this multiple times ({{render}} can't do this)

[A control can be used multiple times](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/tests/helpers/control_test.js#L150)

> 1. Be able to pass in values ({{render}} can't do this)

Like the `{{view}}` helper, `{{control}}` will accept arbitrary name/value pairs. So as in your example, one could manually pass options to the control helper. Like the `{{view}}` helper these options become properties on the view instance:

```
<!-- templates/form/input.hbs -->
<label class="control-label" {{bindAttr for="view.inputId"}}>
  {{view.label}}
</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input {{bindAttr id="view.inputId" name="view.name" type="type" placeholder="view.placeholder"}}>
  <span class="help-block">{{view.help}}</span>
</div>

// controllers/form_input.js
App.FormInputController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  type: "text"
});

// views/form_input.js
App.FormInputView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ["control-group"]
});

<!-- templates/application.hbs -->
{{control "form/input" 
    inputId="account.email" 
    name="email"
    label="Email" 
    placeholder="jpublic@email.com" 
    help="We just need a valid email address."
}}
```

See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uwifev/6/edit) for working example

Also keep in mind that [A control can specify a model to use in its template](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/tests/helpers/control_test.js#L136) - with this in place we can bind properties to model data. Also [if a controller's model changes, its child controllers are destroyed](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/tests/helpers/control_test.js#L198) so the control will reset as expected if the model is swapped out.