# {{outlet}}, {{view}}, {{render}}, and {{control}} helpers

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to put together a simple master-details Ember app. Directory *tree* on one side and file list on another.

Ember offers few helpers to render context into a view. Which of them I can use for:

1. Subtrees of the directory tree.
2. Details list.

In fact, would be very helpful if someone can point me to any docs I can read about the  difference between `{{render view}}`, `{{view view}}` and `{{control view}}` helpers and how to use them properly.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`{{view "directory"}}` renders the view within the context of the current controller.

`{{render "directory"}}` renders the view `App.DirectoryView` with template `directory` within the context of the singleton `App.DirectoryController`

`{{control directory}}` behaves the same way as `render` only it creates a new instance of `App.DirectoryController` every time it renders (unlike `render` which uses the same controller instance every time).

#### Update 18 Feb 2014: `{{control}}` has been removed.

The last two helpers are relatively new, so there isn't much documentation about them. You can find `{{view}}` documentation [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/).

Now looking at your use case, I don't think you need any of these helpers.  Just use nested routes and the `{{outlet}}` helper and it should just work.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('directories', function() {
     this.resource('directory', { path: '/:directory_id'}, function() {
       this.route('files');
     });
  });
});
```

You can build on that following [this guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/).

#### UPDATE: `{{render}}` now creates a new instance every time if you pass a model.

Comment: It seemed `{{control}}` was deprecated but it was not easy to confirm!

Answer (score 10):

For a very **good explanation of the helpers render, partial, outlet and template** have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802223/different-rendering-techniques-in-emberjs-handlebars-template/14802424#14802424).

Just as a rough a summary, how one might use those helpers:

**{{render "navigation"}}** -> Renders the NavigationController and NavigationView at this place. This is helper is good for places, where the Controller and View do not change, e.g. a navigation.

**{{outlet "detailsOutlet"}}** -> This will provide a stub/hook/point into which you can render Components(Controller + View). One would use this with the [render method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) of routes. In your case you will likely have a details route which could look like this. This would render the DetailsController with DetailsView into the outlet 'detailsOutlet' of the index template.

```
App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('details', {   // the template/view to render -> results in App.DetailsView
      into: 'index',          // the template to render into -> where the outlet is defined
      outlet: 'detailsOutlet',       // the name of the outlet in that template -> see above
    });
  }
});
```

**{{view App.DetailsView}}** -> This will render the given view, while preserving the current context/controller. One might change the context, e.g. using your master entity and pass its details to a view like this:

> {{view App.DetailsView contextBinding="masterEntity.details"}}

This is helper is useful, when you want to encapsulate certain parts of a component in subviews, that have own custom logic like handling of actions/events.

**{{control}}** I know that control instantiates a new controller every time it is used, but I cannot see a good fit for your, nor have i a good example for using it.

Comment: Hi @mavilein how this {{view App.DetailsView}}  will render the Details template inside the another page ? I have tried this but getting this error  ""Assertion Failed: An error occured while setting up template bindings. Please check "allSections" template for invalid markup or bindings within HTML comments.""