# how to build nested views in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to learn ember and to understand all concepts. I'm stucked now for a couple of days.

I tried to create a view with multiple "subviews" (is there a name for it in ember?). For example:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+------------------+
| Post title                                    | new tag: ______  |
+-----------------------------------------------+                  |
| Post text                                     | * tag 1          |
|                                               | * tag 2          |
|                                               |                  |
+-----------------------------------------------+------------------+
| New comment: _____________ submit             | related posts    |
|                                               |                  |
| * comment 1 text                              | * post 1         |
| * comment 2 text                              | * post 2         |
| * comment 3 text                              |                  |
| * comment 4 text                              |                  |
| * comment 5 text                              |                  |
|                                               |                  |
+-----------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

My idea is to have a PostController with its own route to show details for a selected post. Adding nested elements for comments and widgets (with `{{#each}}`) is easy. This means I need to handle all actions and everything else for my nested elements in my PostController which smells bad and becomes messy.

Shouldn't be each of them (comments, tags and related) a [separate controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)? In this case I could keep my PostController clean and handle all nested action in its own controller. Is this the right way or has ember better ways to do it?

If yes, how can I implement these nested views. I read many topics around nested views in ember but I can't figure out its concepts. I would say, I don't need routes for tags and comments because its bound to a PostController and they are never used without a post, but I'm not sure.

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14802424/1830500), I tried to use render but I don't understand the concept which controller and view is used in this case.

Is there maybe a good (updated) guide which I just missed or could someone please explain me how this could work or guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create separated views by `Em.View.create`,
then insert to `post` template with `{{view}}` for comments & tags.

Templates:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='post'>
<div class='post'>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class='content'>{{{content}}}</div>
  <div class='tags'>{{view App.TagView}}</div>
  <div class='comments'>{{view App.CommentView}}</div>
  <div class='relatedPosts'>{{view App.RelatedPostView}}</div>
</div>
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='comment'>
{{#each view.comments}}
  <!--some HTML codes for comments-->
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Script:

```
App.CommentView = Em.View.create({
  templateName:'comment',
  comments:[],
  didInsertElement: function(){
    // Handler related to this view has to implement here
    // as there are delays for inserting elements
  }
});

App.PostController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  getContent: function(){
    //some codes for loading content

    //You can implement all methods in single controller
    this.addComments(data.comments);

    //Or call other methods after loaded the content
    App.commentController.setup(data.comments);
  },
  addComments: function(data){
    App.CommentView.set('comments',data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks promising but this means I need to handle all action from my views within `PostController`, right? Shouldn't this be separated into own controllers?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can call any methods after loaded the post.

Comment: Thanks again! But I mean, how would you implement a `TextField` + `Button` with an action like `addComment`. Using your example, I have to define this function in `PostController` because there is no `CommentController`. What if I have multiple actions to handle in a view (like adding, deleting, renaming tags). In this case I need to add this three function to `PostController` as well which blows up my `PostController`, because it handles actions for x views. Is there a rule of thumb when to use views only and when routes with controller and so on?

Comment: You can create a CommentController w/o routes and specify target like `{{action addComment target='App.commentController'}}`. [Reference](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_action)

Comment: This sounds great! I'll try it.